# Missing Overview tab in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I am watching a MySQL tutorial video and the instructor is using version 5.x and he seems to have the *Overview* tab next where the *Output* and *Snippet* tabs are located.

I have 6.3 and I cannot for the life of me find it in my version. Does anyone know where it went?

Comment: all commands in the 'overview' tab are available in 'schema' window, they may remove it in 6.3 version.

Comment: Its a shame if true, I really prefer how it used to look. Thanks for the response.

Comment: you are welcome, you can run both versions 5.x and 6.3 (I do that now), I am using the portable versions of them.

Comment: That might be a good idea. Are there lots of improvements/additions in 6.3 that are missing in the older versions?

Comment: this is the first time I run 6.3, so I can not compare them , but the improvements should be found on: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-63.html